# Farsi/Arabic number to be outputted properly

Tags: html, css, fonts, farsi

You have a file that outputs as such:

```
<div id="first">1</div>
2
<div id="third">
    <? $i = 3; echo(i) ?>
</div>
```

Which outputs:

```
1
2
3
```

Now if I want to have an output as below:

```
?
?
?
```

Well, I was hoping I could output the Arabic/Farsi version of 1,2,3 instead of '?'. How can I use HTML/CSS convert to numbers to Arabic/Farsi?

And why does everything change except numbers when I change my language (Windows XP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no automated way to change numbers, or even digits. Set up a mapping between then and convert manually.
2. Numbers are never localized, because unlike natural language words, Arabic numerals are understood across most of the world.

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't it be slow to go through all character with javascript to convert them one by one?

Comment: Hmm, then how can I convert 'echo($i)' which outputs English to Arabic?

Comment: `$mapping = Array('0' => '۰', '1' => '۱', ...); echo $mapping['1'];`

Comment: fair enough. I just wish all people talked the same language, literally, or better thank god I'm not doing this in Chinese... lol

Answer (score 4):

If you want to number a list, you could use an `ol` element and change the [`list-style-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#list-content) of it like:

```
ol {
    list-style: arabic-indic;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that the numbers are every where not just in the ol/ul

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on ShirzITCo and Kirk Woll's answer above -- which saved my but when client decided all the content in a WordPress CMS should use Eastern-Arabic numerals instead of the Western Arabic they started with:

```
function recursiveReplace(node) {
  if (node.nodeType === 3) { // text node
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue
    .replace(/0/g,'۰')
    .replace(/1/g,'۱')
    .replace(/2/g,'۲')
    .replace(/3/g,'۳')
    .replace(/4/g,'۴')
    .replace(/5/g,'۵')
    .replace(/6/g,'۶')
    .replace(/7/g,'۷')
    .replace(/8/g,'۸')
    .replace(/9/g,'۹');
  } else if (node.nodeType === 1) { // element
    $(node).contents().each(function () {
      recursiveReplace(this);
    });
  }
}
recursiveReplace(document.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following JavaScript code. This will replace numbers:

```
function recursiveReplace(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) { // text node
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("1", "۱");
    } else if (node.nodeType == 1) { // element
        $(node).contents().each(function () {
            recursiveReplace(this);
        });
    }
}

recursiveReplace(document.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use CSS:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: persian
}
```